# How to introduce variables in Makefile

Tags: ubuntu, make, gnu-make

I'm using **Bash** on **Ubuntu** and **GNU Make 4.2.1**.

I'm trying to write a Makefile that would perform simple operations on some data (.TXT files) I have.
My different .TXT files are stored in 3 directories data/dir1 , data/dir2 and data/dir3.

For example, I would like to be able to type make count_dir1 or make count_dir2 or make count_dir3 in order to get the total number of lines withing a directory.

Without using a Makefile, I know how to do so when let's say my current directory is data/dir1 :

```
find . -name '*.TXT*' -type f | xargs wc -l
```

I get the number of lines of each file and the grand total which is exactly what I want.

Now, as for now, my targets basically look like that:

```
count_dir1: /home/data/dir1
    @cd /home/data/dir1 &&\
    find . -name '*.TXT*' -type f | xargs wc -l


count_dir2: /home/data/dir2
    @cd /home/data/dir2 &&\
    find . -name '*.TXT*' -type f | xargs wc -l

count_dir3: /home/data/dir3
    @cd /home/data/dir3 &&\
    find . -name '*.TXT*' -type f | xargs wc -l
```

So, everything works, but obviously, having three targets when I'm sure one would suffice is not efficient, but I don't know how to do so.
I assume I would have to define some variables like:

```
dirs = /home/data/dir1 /home/data/dir2 /home/data/dir3
```

but then I'm not sure how to achieve my goal and from what I have read, I don't feel like it's a very good option to introduce variables that way.

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: Do you have subdirectories beneath `data/dir1` etc.? If not, then `wc -l data/dir1/*.TXT*` would be enough to do the counting for the first directory. If you have many thousand of files, this would obviously not work, but so wouldn't your `find` solution (the total number of lines would be wrong since `wc` would be invoked multiple times).

Comment: Nope, no subdirectories !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If gmake is standard compliant enough, you could use:

```
DIRS= /home/data/dir1 /home/data/dir2 /home/data/dir3

.PHONY: $(DIRS)

all: $(DIRS)

$(DIRS):
        cd $@ && find . -name '*.TXT*' -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

`.PHONY:` is needed since the directories exist and do not depend from other targets.

Using `xargs` with `find` is deprecated since "execplus" has been introduced in 1988.

If you like shorthands for the long target names, you could add

```
count1: /home/data/dir1

count2: /home/data/dir2

count3: /home/data/dir3
```

to your makefile.

Comment: So how would I call my targets? I would have to type `make /home/data/dir1 ` for instance? Is there a way to type let's `make count1` that would behind call `make /home/data/dir1` like an alias I suppose?

Comment: When I called `make /home/data/dir1` it returned 'make /home/data/dir1 is already up to date'  which I get but I just wanted something to be printed to me, not a filed to be created so that message doesn't help ! Also I just saw your edit and tried called `make count 1` but then I had `make: Nothing to be done for 'count1' ` (guess the Makefile sees count1 as a target without any rule?

Comment: So you forgot to add the `.PHONY: ...` line to the makefile or your version of `gmake` is broken.

Comment: Oops that's my bad I don't why I had changed my `.PHONY:` to `.PHONY=` . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: also for further targets, how can I use DIRS as dependencies and call one of the dir depending on what my target is for instance if my target is `subset_dir2` and I want to refer to /home/data/dir2 accordingly in my rule?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question

Comment: So thanks to your help I now have targets that are variables but let's say I want to create other targets likewise, but these ones would each have a dependency (that would depend on the target I'm calling), i.e my dependency is conditional on my target (if I call target subset1 then dependency `/home/data/dependency1` is used, etc)

Comment: Are you asking because that would result in all potential other targets to depend on always out of date targets like `/home/data/die1`?

Comment: Hmm since it's `.PHONY:` , `/home/data/dir1` is indeed always out-of-date but I wasn't really thinking about that. In count1 (i.e `/home/data/dir1`) I needed to `cd` in `/home/data/dir1` which was okay thanks to `cd $@` with `$@` referring to the target itself. But what if my target is `/home/data/subdir1` and I need to `cd` in `/home/data/dir1` in the recipe (or `/home/data/subdir2` and `cd` in `/home/data/dir2` in recipe)? dir$i in recipe would be conditional/matching with chosen subdir$i in target

Comment: In other words, my targets are now variables thanks to your previous answer, but I'm now wondering how to make the dependencies or recipes vary with the target

Comment: `receipe` is not a term that is used together with `make`, see official man page at: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html and the UNIX make man page at: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/make.1s.html BTW: it is bad practice to write make rules based on directories. The correct way is to write rules that are based on a list of files that is part of the Makefile. If you do that, you will have much less problems.

Comment: Okay but what if my list of files are all the files contained in `/home/data/dir1` ? Also I didn't understand why `$(DIRS)` doesnt' have dependencies since count1 directly relies on the files of `/home/data/dir1`, so shouldn't it be added as dependency?